# Converting a number array toString() in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, tostring

Please don't barate me for asking an "dumb" question but I've been struggling over this for weeks!

Why does this array leave off my leading zeros and convert the [numbers](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) to a different format even after I've used toString() to convert the values to a string?

```
var coords=new Array();
coords[0]=new Array(03336890,"SPOON RIVER NEAR ST. JOSEPH, IL");
coords[1]=new Array(03346500,"EMBARRAS RIVER AT LAWRENCEVILLE, IL");
coords[2]=new Array(03612600,"OHIO RIVER AT OLMSTED");
coords[3]=new Array(05543010,"ILLINOIS RIVER AT SENECA, IL");
coords[4]=new Array(05554300,"INDIAN CREEK NEAR FAIRBURY, IL");
coords[5]=new Array(05576100,"LICK CREEK NEAR WOODSIDE, IL");
coords[6]=new Array(05576195,"SUGAR CREEK NEAR CHATHAM, IL");
coords[7]=new Array(05586300,"ILLINOIS RIVER AT FLORENCE, IL");
coords[8]=new Array(05599490,"BIG MUDDY RIVER AT RTE 127 AT MURPHYSBORO, IL");
coords[9]=new Array(411955088280601,"HANSON GRAVEL PIT AT CULVERT NEAR MORRIS, IL");

for (i=0;i<coords.length;i++){
    coords[i][0].toString();
}
```

Check out the result on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1d1yf3pg/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the numbers in a quote instead of numbers.

```
var coords=new Array();
coords[0]=new Array("03336890","SPOON RIVER NEAR ST. JOSEPH, IL");
coords[1]=new Array("03346500","EMBARRAS RIVER AT LAWRENCEVILLE, IL");
...
```

[image]

Comment: That was so easy it was hard! Thanks for pointing out the obvious! I really needed it!

Comment: Appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you saved the values as a number. javascript automatically saves them internal without the leading zeros, so they get lost before you even call `.toString()` on them. I made you a workaround with your given example witch uses a little trick to give you back the leading zero. Of course this needs some refinement if needed:

```
var i, x = 100

var coords = new Array();
coords[0] = new Array(03336890, "SPOON RIVER NEAR ST. JOSEPH, IL");
coords[1] = new Array(03346500, "EMBARRAS RIVER AT LAWRENCEVILLE, IL");
coords[2] = new Array(03612600, "OHIO RIVER AT OLMSTED");
coords[3] = new Array(05543010, "ILLINOIS RIVER AT SENECA, IL");
coords[4] = new Array(05554300, "INDIAN CREEK NEAR FAIRBURY, IL");
coords[5] = new Array(05576100, "LICK CREEK NEAR WOODSIDE, IL");
coords[6] = new Array(05576195, "SUGAR CREEK NEAR CHATHAM, IL");
coords[7] = new Array(05586300, "ILLINOIS RIVER AT FLORENCE, IL");
coords[8] = new Array(05599490, "BIG MUDDY RIVER AT RTE 127 AT MURPHYSBORO, IL");
coords[9] = new Array(411955088280601, "HANSON GRAVEL PIT AT CULVERT NEAR MORRIS, IL");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (x < 10000000) {
    alert("0" + coords[i]);
  }
}
```

Link to the jsfiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gyjjqnkt/

Comment: This doesn't really resolve the problem of the numbers being converted.